To prove that the roots of a quadratic equation aren't real using real number system.
Here is a question from Calculus by Tom M. Apostol.
It goes as :

Prove using real number axioms and theorems that there exist no real $x$ such that $x^2+2x+2=0$.

Here, the real number axioms mainly refer to the order axioms and it's theorems .
How I have tried:
I like to go by taking each case of $x$ being positive, negative and zero:
Case 1: $x>0$
$$x>0\implies x^2>0 \implies x^2+2x>0\implies x^2+2x+2>0$$
Here the axioms/theorems used are:

For both $a$ and $b$ being positive, $a+b \text{ and } ab$ are positive($>0$)


For $a≠0, a^2>0$

Case 2: $x<0$
$$x<0\implies x^2>0\implies x^2+2>0$$
Further, how can I introduce $2x$ and show that the equation is not equal to zero,as $2x$ is now negative and won't fit the axioms mentioned above ?
Using

$a>b\implies a+c>b+c$, where $c$ is any real number.

$$x^2+2>0\implies x^2+2+2x>2x$$
But this doesn't give the required reason to show that $x^2+2x+2=0$ is not solvable with $x<0$.

Note:  $(x+1)^2\ge0$

@J.W.Tanner Yeah, I can get it this way.But can you please tell if I can get forward with the method I mentioned above or that's wrong ?

Your strategy isn't "wrong" - no mistakes. It's ineffective in this context. You might make it work by thinking about $x$ on either side of $-1$, since that's where the function attains its minumum value.

You cannot proceed naively, avoiding the algebra of a perfect square. You can use something like the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality, but that's derived by using precisely the algebra you need to use here.

@CPofPhysics, the case 1 is ok, but you should improve the proof for the case 2.

@EthanBolker Understood! Thanks for that.

You could do it for $x^2+1$ - substitute $y=x+1$ (a translation) and it is the same problem - the method is adapted to the case where the $y-$axis is not the line of symmetry. This is the basis of all quadratic methods that involve "completing the square" and they are designed precisely to avoid the complication you are facing here.

For any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,,\,$ it results that
$x^2+2x+2=\big(x+1\big)^2+1\geqslant0+1=1;$
indeed the square of any real number is non-negative.
Consequently, there does not exist any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,$ such that
$x^2+2x+2=0\,.$

That was helpful, but can you please tell if I can get forward with the method I mentioned above or that is wrong ?

So, it's not always necessary to build the whole equation, we can use even some already built!! Got it!

@CPofPhysics: Your approach in the question isn’t precisely ‘wrong’ anywhere, but it seems unlikely to work.  As can be seen by graphing it (and other ways), the value $x=0$ isn’t a particularly interesting point on this polynomial, so I wouldn’t expect the case-split on whether $x$ is above/below $0$ to be helpful.  As this answer shows, “completing the square” is straightforward and quickly yields a solution, in this and a lot of other positivity properties of real polynomials.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Yeah,  I got it !
